# Android 5.0 data usage TrafficStats.GetUidTxBytes return incorrect value

Tags: android, xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to let the user check the app's data usage inside my app. So I use

```
float dataRX= (float)TrafficStats.GetUidRxBytes(Android.OS.Process.MyUid())/(float)(1024*1024);
float dataTX= (float)TrafficStats.GetUidTxBytes(Android.OS.Process.MyUid())/(float)(1024*1024);
```

to get the Rx bytes and the Tx bytes. This works fine at Android 4.x. However, When I test my app at Android 5.0, these two function will return very huge numbers which is definitely incorrect. I check the system setting, my app only consume 800kb. So how can I get the correct data usage in Android 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the error happened because I test the app with the emulator. When test with real device, it works fine.